# Wordpress Show Posts if has_category

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I edit The Loop so that only posts that have categories will show? I want to be able to hide posts on the page that don't have categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple resources to help in the future:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

**EDIT**

Because all posts, when created, receive a category, whether it is `uncategorized` or a category that you assign, you can get posts that only have categories set by doing this:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => '-1' //ID of your `uncategorized` category
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
print_r($query);
```

You're essentially, filtering out posts that have the `uncategorized` category and pulling in the rest.

**EDIT 2**

One other thing that may be happening is if you're performing the query after the `while` statement. This came to mind as I looked at your comment where you wrote:

```
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<?php if (has_category()) { get_template_part("post", "archive-view"); } ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The code I posted before should be placed before your `while` statement. Like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'cat' => '-1' //ID of your `uncategorized` category
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I want to show the post if it has any category at all. Could I use a wild card for example in "your category name here"?

Would this work for example?
```<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php if (has_category()) { get_template_part("post", "archive-view"); } ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>```

Comment: @GrantPark Sorry, I mis-read the question. I've edited the answer to include what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for editing, makes sense.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to be working for me. I don't need to explicitly create an "uncategorized" category do I?

Comment: The `uncategorized` category is created by default. In WPAdmin->Posts->Categories what is the ID of the `Uncategorized` category? You can find it by hovering over or clicking `Uncategorized` and finding `tag_ID` in the url. That number is the number that you put in `'cat' => '-{your category id here}'`. Be sure you have the `-` before the ID number.

Answer (score -1):

```
$term_ids = get_terms( 
    'TAXONOMY_NAME', 
    [ // Array of arguments, see get_terms()
        'fields' => 'ids' // Get only term ids to make query lean
    ]
);

if (    $term_ids // Check if we have terms
    && !is_wp_error( $term_ids ) // Check for no WP_Error object
) {
    $args = [
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'TAXONOMY_NAME',
                'terms'    => $term_ids,
            ]
        ],
    ];

$q = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Run your loop as needed. Remeber wp_reset_postdata() after the query
}
```

For more information check following link

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196394/get-list-of-posts-which-have-at-least-one-term-from-a-custom-taxonomy-with-wp-qu